# SQLite: count number of records in multiple tables

Tags: sqlite, count, record

Using SQLite I can get all tablenames in my database:

```
SELECT name AS Tablename FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'
```

Result will be some tablenames, for example:

Tablename:
cars
planes
bus

How could I have a SQL query that will count the number of records for each table that is found, result should be:

Tablename   Records:
cars        100
planes      200
bus         300

I understand that in this example I simply could run 3 SELECT COUNT() statements, however the number of tables can vary so that I can not hardcode a fixed number of SELECT COUNT()

Answer (score 2):

All table and column names in a statement need to be known at the time it is compiled, so you can't do this dynamically.

You'd have to programmatically build up a new query string based on the results of getting the table names from `sqlite_master`. Either one query per table like you mentioned, or all together by creating something that looks like

```
SELECT 'table1' AS Tablename, count(*) AS Records FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2', count(*) FROM table2
-- etc.
```

You don't mention what language you're working in, so in psuedo-code of a functional style:

```
var allcounts = query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'")
                .map(name -> "SELECT '$name' AS Tablename, count(*) AS Records FROM \"$name\"")
                .join(" UNION ALL ");
var totals = query(allcounts);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and pseude-code that gives me an idea.... I use C#.... is the pseudo-code possible to code in C# (I'm a beginner in C#....)

Comment: @Spacewalker I am completely ignorant of C\#, sorry. But I'm sure it's pretty simple to use it to build a string holding the needed SQL.